# Determine what is the type of a image representation - to insert into <img src=".."> [Angular2]

Tags: html, soap, base64, angular2-template, bitmapimage

In my SOAP response, I get a below tag:

```
<a:Base64Bitmap>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</a:Base64Bitmap>
```

This is the data that I need to draw respective image for, in my Angular2 application.

This is either a Bitmap or a byte string, but not a base64 encoded string for sure.

I tried appending `data:image/bmp;....`, but nothing happened.

I am not sure if this is a broken string, but the existing application wroks well using this response. This is the response from the API. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: I have no idea what it would have been, but my guess is that the string is broken. Are you sure that is the whole thing? (it seems kinda short for an actual bitmap)

Comment: I too feel the same. But helpless for the moment. Only that I could do was to ask opinions from others. :) The existing application does seem to parse this <a:Base64Bitmap> very well and show the respective image.

Comment: What kind of API is this coming from by the way? is it something custom, or is it a readymade and available software package?

Comment: All I know is that the existing application(in Silverlight) talks to SOAP apis. I do not know how the existing .NET codebase does this conversion to image urls, as I do not have access to the codebase.